# SharePoint 2013 Emails

Tags: workflow, email, tasks, outlook, sharepoint-email

The workflow for my task it's created , it's should send an email to assigned user once the new task created and i publish the workflow without any error.

My question is i'am using the SharePoint 2013 without configure any email but when I search on google I change the outgoing email by entering (Outbound SMTP server,From address,Reply-to) but still once assign to user no emails getting .

Comment: only one user having the email issue? is that user is local or external user? doed user have email address in his profile.

Comment: Check if local smtp service is running on sharepoint server

Comment: Hi  Waqas
No not only one user and they are local users , the smtp service it's not installed on the server  .

Comment: are you using the exchange server address in outbound url setting?

Comment: Yes i have exchange server address and i'am using it in the outbound url

Comment: should i configure some services before using the workflow or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you already checked your emailserver? I had many cases where SharePoint sent emails, but the mailservers didn´t accept or drop them by various reasons.

You could also check SharePoint logs if there is anything stated in regards of sending the mail.